# how to insert data into db as a serialized object

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

my basic question is how to insert data into DB as a serialized object and how to extract and use it then ... any suggestion !!? 
e.g :

```
{id:1, userId:1, type:PHOTO, time:2008-10-15 12:00:00, data:{photoId:2089, photoName:A trip to the beach}}
```

as you see how could I insert data into column **`Data`** and then to use it !?
another question is that if I stored the **`photoName`** inside **`Data`** instead of using JOINS and get the name from it's table (**`photos`**) according to it's **`Id`** thats will not implement the last update on the **`photoName`** (right !?) besides that I'll not be able to make a relation between table photos and the Current table - `(Id` `=>` `photoId)` -  if I stored data like that .. so part of the problem is that I don't know exactly what kind of information are going to be stored in colum **`Data`** So I can't customize a separate column for every type of these information ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically I see two options for you here.

1. You can store an XML serialized object into the database, and simply use standard XML Serialization, here is an [example](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization) that you can adapt for your needs.
2. You can create a true table for this object, and do things the "Standard" way.

With option 1, filtering/joining/searching on the information in the "data" column although still technically possible, is NOT something i would recommend and would be more for a static storage process in my opinion.  Something like a user settings entity, or some other item that is VERY unlikely to be needed for a backend query.

With option 2, yes, you have to do more work, but if you define the object well, it will be possible.

**Clarification**
With regards to my example in #1 above.  You would write out to a memory stream, etc for the serialization rather than a file.

Comment: what if someone refactors the class, wouldn't that break the stored (old) serialization?

Comment: you could just store the object in the database as xml and then store some metadata in additional db columns

Comment: nice, but if I want the last update to be applied on some data like photoName !!?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to store the data relationally, you're really better off not using a relational database. Several object databases speak JSON and would be able to handle this kind of problem pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it as JSON string and use JSONSerializer of JSON lib

http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html

to convert javabean into json string/object and vice versa.

Generally we use this to store the configuration where no of config parameters are unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding saving an object in your database; you can [serialize your object into xml](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813) using `XDocument.ToString()` and [save it in database](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/XMLdDataType.aspx)'s xml datatype column.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", xmldoc.ToString());
```

Checkout, [Work with XML Data Type in SQL Server](http://www.developer.com/net/net/article.php/3406251/Work-with-XML-Data-Type-in-SQL-Server-2005-from-ADONET-20.htm)